# How to properly bundle the React 17 library with new JSX transform as ES Module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, rollup

I am building a simple library of React components and need to publish as ES Module only package to NPM. Since I am using React 17, I have used new JSX transform. I use rollup and typescript to generate ES package. The generated JS file looks like this:

```
// ./dist/index.js
import { jsx, jsxs } from 'react/jsx-runtime';
import { forwardRef } from 'react';
import { SVGIcon } from './SVGIcon.js';

const Add = forwardRef(function Add(props, ref) {
  return (jsx( /*  */));
});

const Bell = forwardRef(function Add(props, ref) {
  return (jsx( /*  */));
});
```

This looks fine. The TypeScript compiler is adding the `jsx-runtime` to the generated code:

```
import { jsx, jsxs } from 'react/jsx-runtime';
```

However, the problem happens when I try to use this library in another application. Webpack complains that it cannot find `'react/jsx-runtime'`. The precise error is this:

```
error - Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/home/hp/test/node_modules/react/jsx-runtime'
imported from /home/hp/test/node_modules/@hrp/icons/dist/index.js
Did you mean to import react/jsx-runtime.js?
```

It doesn't complain about `react`. When I change extension of the imported module manually (adding `.js` extension) to `'react/jsx-runtime.js'` then it works.

So, how to configure rollup or any other module bundler to add appropriate filename extension for subpath imports from third-party modules?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @Rainning, I did not. There doesn't seem to be any clean solution at a moment.

Comment: @HarshalPatil can you include your tsconfig?

Comment: are you using rollup? webpack?

Comment: @caub I am not using rollup.js as said in the question. Although, I would prefer plain `tsc` over any bundler as I am interested in pure ES Module.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using Rollup [`output.paths`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputpaths).

```
output: {
  dir: './esm',
  format: 'esm',
  paths: {
    'react/jsx-runtime': path.resolve(
      './node_modules/react/jsx-runtime.js'
    ),
  },
  ...
}
```